# pandas series use truncate get specified hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: python, pandas

my data

```
data= [{"content": "11", "title": "刘德华", "info": "2020-01-13 08:56:54", "time": 1578877014},
                  {"content": "22", "title": "刘德", "info": "2020-01-24", "time": 1579877014},
                  {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582877014},
                  {"content": "55", "title": "app", "info": "2020-02-17", "time": 1581877014},
                  {"content": "66", "title": "appstore", "info": "2019-06-30", "time": 1561877014},
                  {"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582876014},
                  {"content": "aa", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-12 eee", "time": 1584000882},
                  {"content": "bb", "title": "Thursday data", "info": "2018-03-12 vvvv", "time": 1520842482},
                  {"content": "cc", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-14 xxx", "time": 1584154305},
                  {"content": "cc", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-03-14 aa", "time": 1552531905},
                  {"content": "cc", "title": "Thursday data", "info": "2020-03-19 data", "time": 1584586305},
                  {"content": "cc", "title": "Thursday data", "info": "2019-11-07 aaa", "time": 1573095105},

                  ]
```

i want get 2020-01-13 08:00:00 to 2020-01-13 10:56:54 
i try use truncate but get is None

```
s=pd.Series(data,index=pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in data],utc=True,  unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai'))
s.truncate("2020-01-13 08:00:00","2020-01-13 10:56:54").tolist()
>>> []
```

but use truncate for  2020-01-13  to 2020-01-13 10:56:54 has get data

```
data],utc=True,  unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai'))
s.truncate("2020-01-13","2020-01-13 10:56:54").tolist()
>>> [{"content": "11", "title": "刘德华", "info": "2020-01-13 08:56:54", "time": 1578877014}]
```

params：before and after must be  2020-01-13 10:56:54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need slicing:

```
s1 = s["2020-01-13 08:00:00":"2020-01-13 10:56:54"]
print (s1)

2020-01-13 08:56:54+08:00    {'content': '11', 'title': '刘德华', 'info': '202...
dtype: object
```

I `truncate` and got few errors, then I correct them, but I also got no value, I guess it is bug.

```
s=pd.Series(data,index=pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in data],utc=True,  unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')).sort_index()
s1 = s.truncate(pd.to_datetime("2020-01-13 08:00:00").tz_localize('utc').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai'),
                pd.to_datetime("2020-01-13 10:56:54").tz_localize('utc').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')).tolist()
```

EDIT: Also checked [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=truncate#truncating-fancy-indexing) and it explain why working same selecting like `"2020-01-13 00:00:00"` and `"2020-01-13`:

> A truncate() convenience function is provided that is similar to slicing. Note that truncate assumes a 0 value for any unspecified date component in a DatetimeIndex in contrast to slicing which returns any partially matching dates

Comment: slicing must use DataFrame?

Comment: @xin.chen - I think slicing is `["2020-01-13 08:00:00":"2020-01-13 10:56:54"]`